# How does Java implement network IO at the lowest level?

Tags: java

There are no keywords in Java that relate to network operations.

The "socket" methods such as in OpenJDK dont seem to talk to the network card on the machine anywhere, they simply tell a socket to "connect" to some IP address.

At the lowest, primitive level, how does the JVM know when to call the network interface card on the machine?

Comment: see also: [Understanding Application binary interface (ABI)](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97478/understanding-application-binary-interface-abi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM itself knows nothing about the network card. When you call a socket function, the JVM will call into your platform's standard library (written in native code), and that will make some kind of call into your operating system's kernel. The kernel has already abstracted the network card into a standard interface, no need for the JVM to try and do that as well.